# How to load Enum from java object

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I am working on Java. Please check my code below:

**TestEnum.java**

```
public class TestEnum
{
     public enum AccountState {
         NEW("new"), OLD("old")
     }
}
```

**MyMain.java**

```
public class MyMain
{
   public static void main(String args[])throws Exception {
      //working fine
      System.out.println(TestEnum.AccountState.NEW);

      // But When I create object for TestEnum by using new ,It's throw error  message

      System.out.println(new TestEnum().AccountState.NEW);
   }
}
```

I am getting below error

**AccountState cannot be resolved or is not a field**
Any one correct me what I did wrong in my code.

Answer (score 2):

(Just adding some more information on top of @StefanBeike's answer).

According to [JLS §8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> Nested enum types are implicitly static. It is permissible to explicitly declare a nested enum type to be static.

So you can reference it using:

```
System.out.println(TestEnum.AccountState.NEW);
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to create a new TestEnum object:

```
System.out.println(TestEnum.AccountState.NEW);
```

your `enum` is `static`.

Beside of that I miss something like that:

```
  public enum AccountState {
    NEW("new"), OLD("old");
    private final String code;

    /**
     * @param code
     */
    private AccountState(final String code) {
      this.code = code;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return code;
    }
  }
```

otherwise you cant declare an `enum` with string value constructor.

Comment: Enums are created when the class is initialised. There is no need nor no valid way to create new Enum instances +1 ( Unsafe.allocateInstance does however ;)